Unable to rename sln file in
I am trying to rename for sln file with a custom name while generating a solution from a c# project template, I have different Project names and sln name is also different and want to keep it different. below is what I have done so for, the name function is not reading the solution as a parameter rather as a string, so when it renames the sln file become {{solution}}.sln. I want it to be replace with the parameter value
I have tried the below code, but have got stuck now
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
    "author": "Sanjyot Agureddy",
    "classifications": [
        "Web API",
        "ASP.NET",
        "Clean Architecture"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "language": "C#",
        "type": "project"
    },
    "identity": "application.Services.Sample",
    "name": "ASP.NET Clean Architecture Solution",
    "shortName": "application-sln",
    "sourceName": "application.Services.Sample",
    "preferNameDirectory": false,
    "symbols": {
        "solution": {
            "type": "parameter",
            "defaultValue": "application-service",
            "replaces": "application-sample",
            "description": "The name of the solution file.",
            "dataType": "text",
            "isRequired": true
        }
    },
    "sources": [
        {
            "source": "./",
            "target": "./",
            "exclude": [
                ".vs/**/*",
                ".git/**/*",
                ".template.config/**/*",
                "templates/**/*",
                "**/*.filelist",
                "**/*.user",
                "**/*.lock.json",
                "*.nuspec"
            ],
            "rename": {
                "application-sample.sln": "{{solution}}.sln"
            }
        }
    ]
}


